# Error an a python program made to make 2 LEDs blink

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, gpio

The LEDs dont blink and i get this error every time i run my python program.

blink.py:4: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.OUT)

blink.py:5: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)

I've done some research into the problem but none of the solutions work

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
while True: 
    GPIO.output(16, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(16, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Does the code work and make the LEDs blink?

Comment: no the LEDs dont blink

Comment: Other than your title says, this is not an error. Also, what solutions did not work? If you don't tell which ones you tried, you could get the same solutions again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using try/except/finally blocks in your while-loop for handling errors? (Let me know if try/except/finally is unfamiliar to you).

Here's an example you can take a look at
http://raspi.tv/2013/rpi-gpio-basics-3-how-to-exit-gpio-programs-cleanly-avoid-warnings-and-protect-your-pi

Good luck!

Comment: Its not familiar to me I don't code in the raspberry pi output system in python.

Comment: Exception handling won't catch `RuntimeWarning` by default (since it's a warning, not an exception). And catching them won't be useful here regardless.

Comment: The warning message itself tells how to disable it. Why not do that?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams My bad! Read it as RunTimeError.

Comment: @EJMC64 And you tried the example i provided? Also I must agree with usr2564301, you say that you've "I've done some research into the problem but none of the solutions work" Can you elaborate? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the GPIO pins are already in use. Were they set up in another script before this? You should perform GPIO cleanup after every use. As @Tommi mentioned in their answer, a try/except/finally block is useful for triggering cleanup afterwards. Here is an example demonstrating this, adapted from [this site](http://raspi.tv/2013/rpi-gpio-basics-3-how-to-exit-gpio-programs-cleanly-avoid-warnings-and-protect-your-pi).

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Consider calling GPIO.cleanup() first

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)

try:  
    # Your code here 
    while True: 
        GPIO.output(16, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(16, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(1) # This line should be here so it is part of the while loop

except KeyboardInterrupt:  
    # Here you put any code you want to run before the program   
    # exits when you press CTRL+C  
    print("Keyboard interrupt")  

except:  
    # This catches ALL other exceptions including errors.  
    # You won't get any error messages for debugging  
    # so only use it once your code is working  
    print("Other error or exception occurred!")

finally:  
    GPIO.cleanup() # This ensures a clean exit
```

Comment: I tried using your code and putting GPIO.cleanup first but it still doesn't work and i still get warning messages

Comment: OK, I’ll get thinking!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the raspberry pi 3B GPIO pins are not in order, the place i was using them said it was in order but it was not. So after fixing one light blinks and one light continuously stays on but i need both to blink i shall look further.

Comment: Good job making some progress though!